# XCODE Let me know how to sort numeric size

Tags: xcode, sorting

The following is my code:

```
NSArray *myarr = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"2",@"13",@"1",@"21",@"300",@"4", nil];
NSSortDescriptor *desc = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc]initWithKey:@"self" ascending:YES];
NSArray *rrrr = [myarr sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:desc]];
NSLog(@"%@",rrrr);
```

The following is my result:

```
1,
13,
2,
21,
300,
4
```

While the following is my expected result:

```
1,
2,
4,
13,
21,
300
```

Comment: sortedArrayUsingFunction or sortedArrayUsingSelector.

Comment: Or sortedArrayUsingComparator

Answer (score 0):

Your objects are strings, not numbers. Try this:

```
NSArray *myarr = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@2,@13,@1,@21,@300,@4, nil];
NSSortDescriptor *desc = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc]initWithKey:@"self" ascending:YES];
NSArray *rrrr = [myarr sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:desc]];
NSLog(@"%@",rrrr);
```

You're getting an alphabetical sort rather than a numerical sort. See if you get different results with that code instead.

Comment: Just to be clear: What you're doing there is sorting NSNumber objects rather than NSString objects.  Not changing the actual sort.